# How to cloak DOM element with AngularJS until input has value

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to cloak a DOM element until an input field has any value in it. How can I achieve this with `ng-cloak`?

```
<div>
  <input data-ng-model="search.$" placeholder="Search" type="text" id='search-bar' />
</div>

<div class="single_review text_centered">
  This only displays if the #search-bar has an input value.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `ng-show`:

Example:

```
<div class="single_review text_centered" ng-show="search.$.length">
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/xDmsDOQC8R0qXHgl9VWl?p=preview

Note that if you only use `ng-show="search.$"` instead of `ng-show="search.$.length"` the div will not show if you type "f" or "false" as they are considered falsy.

An alternative is `ng-if`, but then the div would actually be inserted/removed from the DOM instead of just shown/hidden.

Comment: [the div will not show if you type "f" or "false" as they are considered falsy] I know this is in the angular implementation but I don't really know why is set up like that in js 'f' and 'false' is true ^^

Answer (score 0):

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

This is not what you are trying to do.  If you are on Angular 1.2+ (I believe) you can do

```
<div class="single_review text_centered" ng-if="search.$.length">
   This only displays if the #search-bar has an input value.
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can do:

```
<div class="single_review text_centered" ng-show="search.$.length">
   This only displays if the #search-bar has an input value.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an other way (more verbose ^^ but according to the note of @tasseKATT can be safer):

```
app.directive("myCloack", function() {
            return {
                link:function(scope,el){
                    el.css('display','none')
                    scope.$watch('search.$',function(newValue){
                        if(newValue){
                            el.css('display','block')
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

to play around

```
<div>
    <input data-ng-model="search.$" placeholder="Search" type="text" id='search-bar' ng-init="mysearch=false" ng-change="mysearch=true" />
</div>
<div class="single_review text_centered" ng-show="mysearch" >
    This only displays if the #search-bar has an input value.
</div>
```